# dropdown onchange event not firing until second instance

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, onchange

I am having the strangest problem, although I'm sure it's something simple - I'm stumped.  I have an event that hides and shows divs based on a dropdown menu.  When I pick something from my menu it does absolutely nothing.  However, if I change it to a second selection, it works perfectly.  Anyone know what I screwed up?  Thanks for any and all assistance.

```
function call1()
{
document.getElementById("quest1").onchange = function () {
  alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");
  var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("area1z").style.display = (val == "0") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1a").style.display = (val == "1") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1b").style.display = (val == "2") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1c").style.display = (val == "3") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1d").style.display = (val == "4") ? "block" : "none";
};
}

<select id="quest1" onChange="call1()">
<option value=0></option>
<option value=1>Stretch (Maintaining a lifestyle choice for an amount of time)            </option>
<option value=2>Sum (i.e. saving money, counting workouts, etc.</option>
<option value=3>Loss (i.e. Weightloss)</option>
<option value=4>None</option>
</select>

<div id=area1z style="display:none">Please Choose a Quest</div>
<div id=area1a style="display:none">Stretch</div>
<div id=area1b style="display:none">Sum</div>
<div id=area1c style="display:none">Loss</div>
<div id=area1d style="display:none">None</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `onChange()` from following:

```
<select id="quest1" onChange="call1()">
```

Write in this way:

```
document.getElementById("quest1").onchange = function () {
  alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");
  var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  document.getElementById("area1z").style.display = (val == "0") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1a").style.display = (val == "1") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1b").style.display = (val == "2") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1c").style.display = (val == "3") ? "block" : "none";
  document.getElementById("area1d").style.display = (val == "4") ? "block" : "none";
};
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7sS9e/)

Comment: Thank you Dhaval!  For anyone with a similar problem, the reason I couldn't get it to work was because the js was in the head not the body....facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

```
              <script>
                            function call1()
                        {

                          alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");
                          var val=document.getElementById("quest1").value;
                          alert(val);
                          document.getElementById("area1z").style.display = (val == "0") ? "block" : "none";
                          document.getElementById("area1a").style.display = (val == "1") ? "block" : "none";
                          document.getElementById("area1b").style.display = (val == "2") ? "block" : "none";
                          document.getElementById("area1c").style.display = (val == "3") ? "block" : "none";
                          document.getElementById("area1d").style.display = (val == "4") ? "block" : "none";

                        }
                        </script>
                        <select id="quest1" onChange="call1()">
                        <option value="0"></option>
                        <option value="1">Stretch (Maintaining a lifestyle choice for an amount of time)            </option>
                        <option value="2">Sum (i.e. saving money, counting workouts, etc.</option>
                        <option value="3">Loss (i.e. Weightloss)</option>
                        <option value="4">None</option>
                        </select>

                        <div id="area1z" style="display:none">Please Choose a Quest</div>
                        <div id="area1a" style="display:none">Stretch</div>
                        <div id="area1b" style="display:none">Sum</div>
                        <div id="area1c" style="display:none">Loss</div>
                        <div id="area1d" style="display:none">None</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you!  It won't let me mark it as answered because it's too soon, but I will in a couple minutes!  Thank you for your help! (EDIT) spoke too soon.  The alert comes up now, but the divs don't show ever.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Demo that you are trying to do.

Either you remove the "onchaange" or the  "document.getElementById("quest1").onchange =              function () {}" from the code.

```
document.getElementById("quest1").onchange = function () {
  alert("ON CHANGE FIRED");
    var val = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("area1z").style.display = (val == "0") ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("area1a").style.display = (val == "1") ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("area1b").style.display = (val == "2") ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("area1c").style.display = (val == "3") ? "block" : "none";
    document.getElementById("area1d").style.display = (val == "4") ? "block" : "none";
  };
```

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/2M74g/1/